# How do professional programs process huge amounts of data from websockets?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm just learning Python. I would like to receive data from the exchange for all coins via a websocket. But the loop does not have time to process so much data and the queue gradually accumulates. I don’t understand how screener sites process so much in parallel and don’t slow down. Can you tell me please how this is implemented, at least roughly?
Simple example, how i impletement one of part:

```
import websockets
import json
from multiprocessing import Manager

async def method(add_symbols, bookTickers):
    manager = Manager()
    async for websocket in websockets.connect('wss://fstream.binance.com/ws'):
        await websocket.send(json.dumps({
            "method": "SUBSCRIBE",
            "params":
            [ el.lower() + '@bookTicker' for el in add_symbols],
            "id": 1
        }))
        result = await websocket.recv()
        for symbol in add_symbols:
            bookTickers[symbol] = manager.dict()

        async for message in websocket:
            result = json.loads(message)
            symbol = result['s']
            best_bid = result['b']
            best_ask = result['a']
            bookTickers[result['s']]['best_bid'] = best_bid
            bookTickers[result['s']]['best_ask'] = best_ask
```

Comment: Well firstly: they have (likely) wayyy more powerfull servers than you. Second they don't use Python, it's universaly known that python is just not that fast (sadly). And third: they not only have more powerfull servers, they have multiple of them, which makes load balancing possible

Comment: @DerSchinken Thank you very much for your answer, now i understand what exactly the problem is

Comment: In a sentence, the key is "horizontal scalability"

Comment: Move ```json.loads``` out of the receiving process and try ```multiprocessing.Queue```. ```multiprocessing.Manager``` has a serializer so you are de-serializing and re-serializing every packet.

Comment: @jwal Great. Thank you very much, I'll try to use it